# Angular double loop over same data

Tags: angularjs

I have the following code for angularjs:

```
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <div ng-repeat="data in job.data"><!-- get unique loads -->
            <!-- output load -->
            <input type="text" ng-model="data.value"/><!-- output load inputs -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

function myCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.job = {data:[{name:'a',value:'',load:0},{name:'b',value:'',load:0},{name:'a',value:'',load:1},{name:'b',value:'',load:1}]};
}
```

And want the following

```
<div>
    1
    <input type="text" name="(0a)">
    <input type="text" name="(0b)">
</div>
<div>
    2
    <input type="text" name="(1a)">
    <input type="text" name="(1b)">
</div>
```

I have tried creating two filters, one that identifies the unique loads and one that identifies the objects with that specific load, however when I remove items from the data it, angular has 
lost the reference (as it is not actual the looped data) and hence does not clean up the DOM correctly.

I tried with a $watchCollection on job.data as well, where I create a $scope.loads array with the loads, but the  also looses the references and does not clean up the DOM.

So what is the correct way of achieving the wanted output, where I am able to change the job.data and the DOM is updated correctly?

Comment: Actually, it had the same bug not updating the DOM correctly but then I got a hunch that it had to be something else. It turns out that bs-form-control has a bug, when I wrapped the bs-form-control in a extra div with the ng-repeat everything works. But your solution actually answers the issue on how to handle the double loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to transform your data structure to support the "loop by load" paradigm. Try

```
_.uniq(
  _.map(
    _.sortBy(
      $scope.job.data,
      'load'
    ),
    function (item) {
      return item.load;
    }
  )
)
```

(using [Lodash](https://lodash.com/)) to get the loads and then just loop loads on outer level and filter by load on inner level.